# pandas: modify a string value based on its rank in column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to modify the value of a string based on the rank of that string in the column. I am stuck and I can't find resources to troubleshoot.

Here is what the problem looks like:

```
    Id Supplier  Quantity
0  001      XXX        10
1  001      XYZ        12
2  002      XWA         9
3  002      XFF        15
4  003      WQE         6
```

and here is what I have been able to do alone (the easy part)

```
dataset = datatest.groupby('Id').apply(pd.DataFrame.sort_values,by='Quantity', ascending=False)
```

but after that I can't find a way to:
- select the values in 'Id' that are not the first one
- add the suffix '-S' at the end of each of them to get the end result like:

```
      Id Supplier  Quantity
0    001      XYZ        12
1  001-S      XXX        10
2    002      XFE        15
3  002-S      XWA         9
4    003      WQE         6
```

I get what I need to do but my underlying problem is that I don't what tool could help me do that operation

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `groupby` for the easy part:

```
dataset = datatest.sort_values(['Id','Quantity'], ascending=[True, False])

dataset.loc[dataset.duplicated('Id'),'Id'] += '-S'
```

Output:

```
      Id Supplier Quantity
0    001      XXX       10
1  001-S      XYZ       12
3    002      XFF       15
2  002-S      XWA        9
4    003      WQE        6
```

Comment: that works, thank you so much. The only thing was that groupby is necessary to sort Quantity ascendingly for each Id value

Answer (score 0):

```
aList = dataset.Id
IDs = []
for i in aList[0:-1:2]:
    IDs.append(i+'-S')
dataset.Id = IDs
```

There's definitely a better way to do this, but this should do the trick if you're all you're looking to do is apply '-S' to every other element in your Id column